# How to manipulate the underlying Text View within a Window?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

This is a document-based app. I want to manipulate the underlying text view within my window.  I set it up as follows:

[image]
So I also created an outlet to my document  class to manipulate it.

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
```

Though it doesn't respond to any methods I call on it. Just to test, i want  the textview to load with inserted text but the textview doesn't respond at all.

```
self.textView.string = @"Hello world";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that and see if it gets called. Also, what method are you doing this in?

Comment: The window's delegate is the text view???

Comment: @ChrisLoonam the breakpoint hits. I'm calling it from applicationDidFinishLaunching

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to the text view initialized from the nib until the nib has loaded and the text view has been created. At that point, `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` is called, and the nib objects are instantiated. Until then, the `textView` outlet is nil. So I'm guessing that that's the problem.

Comment: I'm calling it from applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: Well the textview is nil- but shouldn't t be loaded by applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: It's a document-based app. It's a document. The application launches, and then you get a document. Read what I said in my answer! You must wait until after `windowControllerDidLoadNib:`.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/KeyObjects/KeyObjects.html

Comment: "**Post-nib-loading code**. This override provides a place for code to be executed after the document window nib file is loaded. For example, *objects in the nib cannot be initialized until after the nib is loaded*." (My italics)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/ManagingLifecycle/ManagingLifecycle.html

Comment: "Of course, you cannot send messages to user interface objects until after the nib file loads. So, you can do such operations in `windowControllerDidLoadNib:`."

Comment: I implemented my own window controller.  In that case, I override windowDidLoad:  from the window controller.  But whether  its windowControllerDidLoad: or windowDidLoad:, applicationDidFinishLaunching: gets called last. I logged each method to verify.

Comment: Your screen shot suggests that the document is the one with the outlet to the text view. What I am suggesting is that you check the value of `self.textView` in the document in `windowControllerDidLoadNib:`. If it is nil *there*, something is wrong with the outlet.